# How to get directory of a folder inside xcode project? ios swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have bunch of tile images inside the folder called "Tiles"

I need to extract one image at a time from that folder, and set it to UIView object.

I am stuck on how to get the image from inside that folder.

Can anyone help do this in Swift?

[image]

Comment: Actually it's not necessarily in that folder, because it's a just a group for organizing files visibly in Xcode, your files can be somewhere else. Did you created a real folder called Tiles that contains all that .swift files?

Comment: no i didn't. only in xcode project like the screenshot. How do i get the file then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the image name,you can just access the image in this folder like this

```
let image = UIImage(named: "image.png")
```

Or this

```
let imageURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("image", withExtension: "png")
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL!.path!)
```

**If you want get all images,you create a real folder inside the project**

```
 let imageArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLsForResourcesWithExtension("png", subdirectory: "Titles") as! [NSURL]
```

This will return an urlArray of png inside Titles folder.You can use `contentsOfFile` as show before to access image

Comment: I think he wants to get all images in the "Titles" folder.

Comment: Understanding that folders don't mean anything more than just 'grouping' for convenience helped.

Comment: @Leo My folder structure is like this http://prntscr.com/jx4w92 and i want to fetch all the images inside Stickers folder for that i have used  `        __let imageArray = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "png", subdirectory: "Stickers") as! [URL]
__    but it won't work. Please Help

Comment: @KhushbuDesai It is not a **real folder**, a real folder looks like blue. You may right click the image, then select show in Finder to check real folder

Comment: @Leo http://prntscr.com/jxfped Please check the screen shot, I have one folder as Goodies and i want to get all the images inside that folder for this i have used ___let imageArray = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "png", subdirectory: "Goodies") as! [URL]___ but it give me empty array, Please Help what i am doing wrong